# Как в google test записать сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: c++

У меня есть макрос, который вызывает немедленное завершение работы программы.

```
#define MI_IMMEDIATE_CRASH() __debugbreak()

int foo(int value){
  if (value == 0) {
    // Тут я хочу оставить какое-то сообщение, например
    // message("Value was zero! :( ");
    MI_IMMEDIATE_CRASH();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Теперь я пишу тест:

```
TEST(Foo, Test1){
  EXPECT_DEATH(foo(0), "Value was zero! :(");
}
```

Я долго (очень долго) пытался найти в исходниках google test какую-нибудь функцию, которая могла бы записать сообщение об ошибке, но так и не смог это сделать.

Есть вообще что-то такое?

Comment: А посмотреть в [документаци](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html)? Там в первом абзаце написано: `EXPECT_TRUE(my_condition) << "My condition is not true";`

Comment: Перед EXPECT_DEATH следует добавить проверку получения сообщения посредством IPC или какого-то другого механизма. Падение программы само по себе не подразумевает отправки сообщения. @AlexeyVesker Это пример для обычной проверки, а в вопросе речь про другой процесс.